# Android LayoutTransition

Tags: android, layouttransition

I want to use the `LayoutTransition` class that it can achieve animation.But Eclipse tell me `Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7)`. And I just want to call this API in Android2.1+. So, Here What way can be deal with it(such as the Open Sources library)?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Add support library and try.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from Android Lint. You can suppress it by adding an
`@SuppressLint("NewApi")`. Then in the body of the method using `LayoutTransition` you can add the following code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   //use LayoutTransition in your code
} else {
   //on Android 7-11, don't use LayoutTransition
}
```